Milvus exception: index not found in FLAT collection
I am having a strange issue in milvus vector search collection.
Just for a test case i create a generic vectors samples. When i define the collection search method to be FLAT,create index and then try to load it I get the error :
<MilvusException: (code=25, message=index not found[collection="my_collection_name"]

However when trying any other search method, everything works fine.
I tried also to omit the create index (not necessary for FLAT method) and got the same exception.
Has anyone ever encountered this error and able to assist.
Relevant Code::
def create_vector_collection(collection_name, fields, description, host, port):
    connections.connect(host=host, port=port)
    schema = CollectionSchema(fields=fields, description=description)
    return Collection(name=collection_name, schema=schema)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pymilvus import connections, Collection
    connections.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT)
    fields = [
        FieldSchema(name="id", dtype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True, auto_id=True),
        FieldSchema(name="embedding", dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=1024),
        FieldSchema(name="smiles", dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=3000)
    ]
    description = "A collection with vectors and metadata"
    brute_force_collection_name = "molecule_brute_force_collection"
    brute_force_collection = create_vector_collection(brute_force_collection_name, fields, description, host=HOST, port=PORT)

    create_fp_array('MarketSelectSmiles.smi', chunk_size=1000, collections=[brute_force_collection])

    brute_force_index_params = {
        "index_type": "FLAT",
        "metric_type": "L2",
        "params": {}
    }

    res = brute_force_collection.create_index(field_name="embedding", index_params=brute_force_index_params)
    collection = Collection(brute_force_collection_name)
    collection.load()#FAILS at this point :(
    print(f"Collection '{brute_force_collection_name}' loaded successfully.")

create_fp_array upload from a file 1000 vectors to the collection each time, as already been said other index methods such as IVF_FLAT are operational(probelm exists only with FLAT).
